# How to select only the records whose primary keys are only int types and vice versa?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, database-design, primary-key

Suppose I have a table in which the primary keys are double types ; 1, 1.2,1.4, 3,3.2,5,6.2,7 and so on..

In Microsoft Access, I would like to have a record source or a record set that is based on a query(sql statement) to select only the records with primary keys 1,3,5 and 7. Similarly I would also like to have a query that selects only the double types(1.2,1.4,3.2 and 6.2). How do I make such a query?

Comment: Does **primary keys** means **integer keys** or **[Prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where pk = int(pk);
```

The query for the decimal types is quite similar.

By the way, `double` is a very bad type for a primary key.  Two values can look the same but be different (this is how floating point representations work).  If you need decimal points for such a key, you should use `decimal` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will use decimal in that case. So the query to select only decimal types would be exactly the same thing except the last line 'where pk = decimal(pk)'  ?

Comment: No, the query would be `pk <> int(pk)`.